# Alignment Issue with </div>

Tags: html, css

Could someone please help me with the following issue. You will see that in the very top header menu I have login form far left and telephone number far right and all seems okay.

Now having run the site through W3C it is showing a missing `</div>` which I can see the above needs; however, when applied and see the following url:  the alignment is all over and I don't know what to amend to get that back to how the original looked. Can someone please assit me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happened here is that something is pushing against your logo. Since it's set to `float:left`, it goes to the left of whatever is pushing against it.

Adding `clear:left` to your logo class means that nothing can push it from the left. It will move out of the way and be as far left as it can.

```
.main-menu .logo {
   clear: left;
   /* Other CSS for logo*/
}
```

Comment: Logo is back: http://www.nomoremist.co.uk/issue/index2.html but menu isn't as is still out of alignment and should be alongside logo, but it is on the orange menu bar instead. Any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems ok here using:

```
.main-menu .logo {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes logo is fine however menu tabs 'HOME' aren't aligned correctly. They should be on the black menu alongside the logo...they aren't and are on the orange section and I need to move them back up if you can help please.

Comment: I've added the CSS to original post also if that helps

Comment: As I said: Try adding 'float:left' to .main-menu .logo - it makes the menu tabs line up as well. Here's a screenshot: http://d.pr/bD7C